# Receber JSON via POST do MoIP numa plataforma C#/.Net MVC

Tags: c#

[C#/.Net][MoIP] Pessoal, uso uma plataforma de pagamentos (MoIP) e ela tem uma função que enviar notificação no formato JSON para a URL que vc cadastrou, que será do seu sistema no servidor. Quero saber agora como eu faço para pegar o BODY desse JSON. Alguém tem algum ideia???
Estou a dias buscando uma solução!!!

Comment: Você cria uma classe com a nomenclatura das chaves idênticas das propriedades do seu json, quando o seu método for chamado ele vai fazer uma conversão implícita dos valores do json para a classe mapeada.

Comment: Ou você deserializa o json para o tipo `dynamic`. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm

Comment: Mas inclua em sua pergunta o método onde você está recebendo o json e o modelo de resposta que está precisando processar.

Comment: eu to na Controller "Filiacoes" e o a função é "Webhook", sendo assim eu cadastrei a url "http://54.233.161.49:8090/Filiacoes/Webhook". Ai eu coloco algo no parametro? Pego ja dentro da função com algum metodo do C#? To muito perdido

Comment: @SandersonCorrêa desenvolvi a biblioteca aqui: github.com/matmiranda/MoipCSharp  para C#